# Como levar o navegador para FullScreen e fazê-lo permanecer em FullScreen quando a página é atualizada?

Tags: javascript

Estou com dificuldade em uma funcionalidade do JavaScript.

Estou tentando colocar o navegador em `fullScreen` a partir de um duplo clique na aplicação Web. Mas quando a página é atualizada, ele sai da `fullScreen`.

Seguem as funções:

```
var fullScreen;
$(document).dblclick(function(){
 alternaFullScreen();
});

function verificaFullScreen(){ // Chamo essa função dentro da ready como tentativa de solução, pra que ele atualize a página e verifique se deve estar em fullScreen e se sim renderize a página já em full screen. 
   if(getCookie('fullScreen') == 'true'){ //getCookie pega o valor da variável salva no cookie.
       entrarFullScreen();
   }
}

function alternaFullScreen(){
    if(fullScreen == true){
        sairFullScreen();
        fullScreen = false;
        setCookieMax('fullScreen', 'false'); //salva o valor da variável no cookie.
    }
    else if(fullScreen == false || fullScreen == null){
        entrarFullScreen();
        fullScreen = true;
        setCookieMax('fullScreen', 'true');   
    }
}

function entrarFullScreen(){
    if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement) { 
        if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
            document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
            document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
    }
}

function sairFullScreen(){
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }
}
```

Como mencionado no comentário, chamo a função `verificaFullScreen` dentro da `ready`, como tentativa de resolver o problema, mas não está dando certo, creio que por algum bloqueio do navegador.

Poderiam me ajudar? Uma solução ou caminho para uma seria muito bem vinda.
Pensei em simular o pressionamento da tecla <kbd>F11</kbd> a partir do duplo clique, mas quando pesquisei encontrei o seguinte:

> Você não pode fazer os computadores das pessoas digitarem coisas através do JavaScript. Isso viola o ambiente de *sandbox* dos navegadores. Eu suponho que você está tentando fazer uma janela ir em tela cheia embora. Esta pergunta SO cobre isso.

Encontrei aqui no Stack OverFlow, não sei até que ponto a informação é valida.

Comment: Eu tive que fazer isso em um projeto uma vez. A minha solução foi criar uma `index.php` que basicamente tinha um `iframe` e a função de `fullscreen`, o botão ficava dentro `iframe` ele executava a função  `fullscreen` do javascript da pagina mãe do `iframe`, as paginas eram abertas no proprio `iframe` então como a pagina `index.php` não mudava ele ficava em `fullscreen`.

Comment: Obrigado Icaro, Vou tentar implementar algo parecido aqui.